# Storing selected portion from the string in Variables in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a variable Field in which a string is store like this:

```
Field= "In Field 'fieldname':(Value1) has changed from (1) to (2)"
```

From this string stored in variable Field, I want to catch the values (1) and (2) in two different varibales like:

```
OldValue=1
NewValue=2
```

Can someone please help me here?
I am handling this variables in Python

Comment: Tagging `python` is fine, but tagging both `python2.7` and `python-3x` doesn't make sense, which one are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This finds digits surrounded by brackets:

```
>>> import re
>>> Field= "In Field 'fieldname':(Value1) has changed from (1) to (2)"
>>> OldValue, NewValue = map(int, re.findall(r'\((\d+)\)', Field))
>>> OldValue
1
>>> NewValue
2
```

You may not only have two values, in which case

```
vals = list(map(int, re.findall(r'\((\d+)\)', Field)))
```

will do the trick

Comment: What changes I have to do if I want to catch: name=fieldname

Comment: Do you want to catch `:`? Like `:(Value1)` as well as the `(1)` `(2)`?

Comment: Also your trick works if a I have int values, suppose if old value and new value is not int, then what will be the changes?

Comment: No I want to cath in name = filedname and change values(also if they are not of type int)

Comment: @hulk007 If they aren't `int`, `re.findall(r'\((\d+)\)', Field)` alone, returns them as strings

Comment: `name=fieldname`, an expression like `r'(\w+) = (\w+)'` is that what you want?

Comment: Yes Now I want to catch in variable: name=fieldname, what will be the expression for it?

Comment: `>>> text = 'name=fieldname  name2=fieldname2'`
`>>> import re`
`>>> re.findall(r'(\w+)=(\w+)', text)`
`[('name', 'fieldname'), ('name2', 'fieldname2')]`

Comment: @hulk007 you can ask a new question if you want for this